# Bash Python script process redirect

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout

Essentially I am trying to redirect my print statements from my python script such that they get appended to my bash logging function. I was trying to take inspiration from here -> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst but this isn't working. Whenever I run this code it just hangs on the python call with nothing being printed. I would imagine this *should* be an easy fix but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
while read line ;do
    log  "$line"
done < <( <Python script> )
...
function log {
   echo "$(date) ($(host)) [$1]"
}
```

Comment: Use `IFS= read -r line` to ensure that `bash` reads each line *verbatim* from the Python script.

Comment: Didn't work :( I did `while IFS= read -r line; do`

Comment: Figured it out... Python was buffering all of the logging statements. By adding a -u it was able to print everything out.